# Z3 4.0 Z3_parse_smtlib2_string

Tags: z3

I am using Z3 with SMT2 via C API/JNA/Scala and seems to work pretty well.

I want to try incremental solving. So at first I translate this by using *Z3_parse_smtlib2_string*:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert (>= x 0))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Then I get back an *Z3_ast*, put it into a solver via *Z3_solver_assert*, check it with Z3_solver_check and retrieve a model via *Z3_solver_get_model* (if the check returned satisfiable, which is the case in this example). So far there is no problem.

But when I want to assert something additionally like this:

```
(assert (= x 1))
```

I get stuck at the point where *Z3_parse_smtlib2_string* is called, because it complains, that x is an unknown constant. If I add also add the *declare-fun* to the second snippet I get an invalid argument error.
Shouldn't this variable exist already in the environment? Do I have to set the additional parameters of *Z3_parse_smtlib2_string*? How can I get those out of the previsously parsed formula?

Also using [(set-option :global-decls true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337783/declare-symbols-that-remain-valid-outside-their-scope) did not work as Z3 tells me that this *option value cannot be modified after initialization*.

Does anybody have a clue how to solve this problem?

Comment: Shameless plug: have you tried [https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3](https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3)? (disclosure: I'm the main author.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Z3_parse_smtlib2_string`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#ga199452aebb37cb160bd6abead8a84d08) can take as extra arguments lists of existing sorts and constants. The second time you call it you can therefore tell it that you already know what `x` stands for.

To recover the declared constants and sorts from the first parsing pass, you can use [`Z3_get_smtlib_num_decls`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#ga33fc0f55a4d60408a6e15d89da5b1cbe), `Z3_get_smtlib_decl` and similarly for sorts.

Comment: Mh.. I was a bit to quick on accepting this answer as the right one. Could it be that the Z3_get_smtlib_X functions work only when calling Z3_parse_smtlib_string or Z3_parse_smtlib_file like the comment says? Because I get the error: parser (data) is not available...

Comment: I found a way to solve this problem: I don't get the information I need (func decls and func names) from the parser but from a model: _Z3_model_get_const_decl_, _Z3_model_get_func_decl_ and _Z3_model_get_decl_name_

These are part of the deprecated API. But as I can see this is the only way to use incremental solving with SMTLIB2. Or does anybody have another suggestion?