# Z3 4.0: get complete model

Tags: z3

I need a complete model of an SMTLIB2 formula:

http://pastebin.com/KiwFJTrK

Z3 (version 3.2 and 4.0) returns values for all variables but not for *var4*. I tried some configuration settings like

```
MODEL_COMPLETION = true
```

but it did not seem to work. Does anybody have a suggestion? CVC3 in comparison returns a model (including var4), so it is not an issue of SMTLIB or my example.

The reason I need this is explained [here in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049918/z3-4-0-z3-parse-smtlib2-string). In short: I want to use the C API for incremental solving. For this reason I have to use the function **Z3_parse_smtlib2_string** multiple times. This function needs previously declared functions and constants as parameters. I am unable to get this information via **Z3_get_smtlib_decl** because these kind of functions work just when **z3_parse_smtlib_string** is called, not **Z3_parse_smtlib2_string**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid this problem by adding the following option in the beginning of your script.

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
```

I will fix it for the next release. 
Here is a short explanation of what is going on.
Z3 has a solver for 0-1 integer problems. After preprocessing, your script is tagged as a 0-1 integer problem by Z3. The value of `var4` is a "don't care" when the problem is viewed as a 0-1 problem, but it is not a "don't care" when the problem is viewed as an integer problem (`var4` must be 0 or 1). By default, Z3 will not display the value of "don't care" variables.

The `MODEL_COMPLETION=true` will complete the model as you request values for constants that are not included in the model. For example, if we execute `(eval var4)`, Z3 will produce an interepretation for `var4`.

Comment: thank you very much, that did the job!
just btw: have you taken a look at the _Z3_get_smtlib_decl_ problem I mentioned? Will there be a function _Z3_get_smtlib2_decl_ or so in the future?

Comment: Yes, in a future release, we will introduce "Parser" objects. Each "Parser" object will have support for retrieving decls, formulas, etc.

Comment: Great! Looking forward to that!