# Z3 4.3: get complete model

Tags: z3

This question is pretty much the same than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115004/z3-4-0-get-complete-model), but the solution is not working for me. Sorry, I would like to comment on that answer instead of asking a new question, but I don't have enough reputation...

I'm modeling [a simple state machine for an elevator](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/VhiR). There are two floors and two buttons *Up* and *Down*. I've modeled a transition as a predicate *Action x Elevator x Elevator* (Elevator = State), such that *T(a,s,s')* holds iff the action *a* may cause the transition from *s* to *s'*, where an action is pushing either the *Up* or the *Down* button. The satisfiability of the problem does not depend on the person who pushes a button, but I would like Z3 to assign some interpretation to the function *subject : Action -> Person*.

The goal is to find a *k*-trace for the state machine that may help understanding the behavior of the elevator.

I've tried different combinations of options, including `auto-config=false` and `model-completion=true`, with no success. I've also tried to force model completion asking for the value of *(subject Action0)*, but Z3 still does not assign an interpretation to *subject*.

My Z3 version is 4.3.1 running on Linux amd64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good example. 
The abstract sort Person does not appear in the assertions, 
and the function that returns a Person is also not used in the 
assertions.

You can force eval to complete the model by passing the parameter directly to the function:

http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Pslt4

In other words, use

```
   (eval <term> :model-completion true)
```

instead of

```
   (eval <term>)
```

A different, but hacky, way is to make sure that the terms you want to evaluate are included in the original model: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Yukv

Answer (score 3):

The problem with parameter `:model-completion` has been fixed. The fix is already available at http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/a895506dac75.

The fix will be available in the next official release. 
If you want you can download the `unstable` (work-in-progress) branch, and compile it. To download, you just have to clink the `Download` button in the link above.

BTW, the new Z3 has a new parameter setting framework that allows us to set internal module parameters. In the next release (and in the `unstable` branch). We have to use

```
(set-option :model_evaluator.completion true)
```

instead of

```
(set-option :model_completion true)
```

because we are setting a parameter of the module `model_evaluator`.
Moreover, we have to use

```
(eval <term> :completion true)
```

instead of

```
(eval <term> :model_completion true)
```

because we are setting the parameter `completion` of the model evaluator.