# eval returns a let statement

Tags: z3

I am running the below SMT2 spec in Z3.  The goal is to get an answer to the `eval` at the end -- either `true` or `false` -- but instead I get a `let` statement.  Is this a bug, or am I supposed to be interpreting the `let` in a certain way?  Compiling by hand gives me `false` and it appears to be pretty straightforward, but Z3 seems to confused.

```
(declare-sort PolymorphicClass 0)

(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!6 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!13 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!2 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!12 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!14 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!10 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!8 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!9 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!15 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!0 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!1 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!11 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!3 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!5 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!4 () PolymorphicClass)
(declare-fun PolymorphicClass!val!7 () PolymorphicClass)

(define-fun k!623 ((x!1 PolymorphicClass)) PolymorphicClass
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!15) PolymorphicClass!val!15
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!2) PolymorphicClass!val!2
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!7) PolymorphicClass!val!7
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!8) PolymorphicClass!val!8
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!10) PolymorphicClass!val!10
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!9) PolymorphicClass!val!9
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!14) PolymorphicClass!val!14
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!0) PolymorphicClass!val!0
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!6) PolymorphicClass!val!6
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!5) PolymorphicClass!val!5
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!1) PolymorphicClass!val!1
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!4) PolymorphicClass!val!4
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!12) PolymorphicClass!val!12
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!11) PolymorphicClass!val!11
    PolymorphicClass!val!13)))))))))))))))

(define-fun isBlog!641 ((x!1 PolymorphicClass)) Bool
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!0) true
  (ite (= x!1 PolymorphicClass!val!1) true
    false)))

(define-fun isBlog ((x!1 PolymorphicClass)) Bool
  (isBlog!641 (k!623 x!1)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)

(eval (isBlog PolymorphicClass!val!6))

(exit)
```

Here is the output I get from Z3:

```
sat
(model 
)
(let ((a!1 (ite (= PolymorphicClass!val!6 PolymorphicClass!val!9)
                PolymorphicClass!val!9
                (ite (= PolymorphicClass!val!6 PolymorphicClass!val!14)
                     PolymorphicClass!val!14
                     (ite (= PolymorphicClass!val!6 PolymorphicClass!val!0)
                          PolymorphicClass!val!0
                          PolymorphicClass!val!6)))))
(let ((a!2 (ite (= PolymorphicClass!val!6 PolymorphicClass!val!7)
                PolymorphicClass!val!7
                (ite (= PolymorphicClass!val!6 PolymorphicClass!val!8)
                     PolymorphicClass!val!8
                     (ite (= PolymorphicClass!val!6 PolymorphicClass!val!10)
                          PolymorphicClass!val!10
                          a!1)))))
(let ((a!3 (ite (= PolymorphicClass!val!6 PolymorphicClass!val!15)
                PolymorphicClass!val!15
                (ite (= PolymorphicClass!val!6 PolymorphicClass!val!2)
                     PolymorphicClass!val!2
                     a!2))))
          (or (= a!3 PolymorphicClass!val!0) (= a!3 PolymorphicClass!val!1)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values have not been used in any real constraints (only in definitions).
You can use model completion to ensure that Z3 evaluates values that have not been used in constraints.

So you can call:

```
   (eval (isBlog PolymorphicClass!val!6) :model-completion true)
```

to get the appropriate evaluation.

See the related question: [Z3 4.3: get complete model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524316/z3-4-3-get-complete-model/14525498#14525498) for additional information.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer!