# Strange result when I ask Z3 for additional solutions

Tags: z3

I am using Z3 as a simple SAT solver, asserting propositional terms as follows:

```
let ctx = new Context()
let x = ctx.MkBoolConst("x")
let y = ctx.MkBoolConst("y")
let z = ctx.MkBoolConst("z")
let f = ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkAnd(x,y), ctx.MkAnd(ctx.MkNot(x),z))
let s = ctx.MkSolver()
s.Assert(f)
assert (s.Check() = Status.SATISFIABLE)
let r= [s.Model.Eval(x); s.Model.Eval(y); s.Model.Eval(z)]
printfn "%A" r
```

Which returns

```
[false; true; true]
```

as expected. However, when i try to ask Z3 for further solutions by taking the and of the found assignments and negating that and adding it back to Z3 solver

```
let mkB(z3_lit:BoolExpr,bvalue:Expr) = 
  if (bvalue:?> BoolExpr).IsTrue then z3_lit else ctx.MkNot z3_lit
let founds = List.map mkB (List.zip [x;y;z] r)
let and_founds = ctx.MkAnd (List.toArray(founds))
let negated = ctx.MkNot and_founds
s.Assert negated
assert (s.Check() = Status.SATISFIABLE)
let r2 = [s.Model.Eval(x); s.Model.Eval(y); s.Model.Eval(z)]
printfn "%A" r2
```

I get a strange assignment to z. ie:

```
[true; true; z]
```

Why is the assignment to z which was previously `true` changed to `z`?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, getting a variable as its own model means it's a "don't care": any value for `z` will give you a valid model. Indeed, in this case, the clause is already satisfied by `x` and `y` being true.

If you want Z3 to complete the model for you, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115004/z3-4-0-get-complete-model).

Also, the C API at least defines an extra argument to [`Z3_model_eval`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#ga86670c291a16640b932e7892176a9d1b), which you can use to indicate to Z3 that you want a value for all variables.

Comment: what you're saying certainly makes sense. I am a bit puzzled as to why it didn't return a dont care for `y` in the first model?

Comment: It could just depends in the order in which Z3 tries to assign values to variables.