# Microsoft Z3 import SMT file

Tags: c#, .net, z3, smt

I want to use Z3 (version 4.5.0.1) with .net and wonder if i can use a SMTLIB file.
So i have this simple smt file that i want to load in my program:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (< x 4))
(assert (< (- y x) 1))
(assert (> y 1))
```

In c# i tryed the folowing:

```
using(Context context = new Context(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "model", "true" } })) {
    context.ParseSMTLIB2String(Resources.SampleSMT2);
    var solver = context.MkOptimize();
    solver.Check();
    Console.WriteLine($"model: {solver.Model}"); // empty
    //BigInteger x = (solver.Model.Evaluate(...) as IntNum).BigInteger;
    //BigInteger y = (solver.Model.Evaluate(...) as IntNum).BigInteger;
}
```

But i dont know how to solve the problem provided in the smt file because in 
this example the model is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParseSMTLIB2String` returns a `BoolExpr` that contains the assertions in the smt2 file, i.e., something like

`BoolExpr be = context.ParseSMTLIB2String(...);
solver.Add(be);
solver.Check();
...`

should get you there.

Comment: thank you for your help but how do i get the ConstInt x and y so i can evaluate them ?

Comment: You'll have to run over the constraints and collect all the consts; see here for links to similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882992/how-to-get-the-declaration-from-a-z3-smtlib2-formula/40182248#40182248